# python multiprocess very slow

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm having trouble using python multiprocess.

im trying with a minimal version of code:

```
import os
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" # just in case the system uses multithrad somehow
os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" # just in case the system uses multithrad somehow
os.environ["MKL_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" # just in case the system uses multithrad somehow
os.environ["VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS"] = "1" # just in case the system uses multithrad somehow
os.environ["NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" # just in case the system uses multithrad somehow
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime as dt
from multiprocessing import Pool
from pandas import DataFrame as DF

def trytrytryshare(times):        
    i = 0
    for j in range(times):
        i+=1
    return


def trymultishare(thread = 70 , times = 10):
    st = dt.now()
    args_l = [(times,) for i in range(thread)]               
    print(st)
    p = Pool(thread)
    for i in range(len(args_l)):
       p.apply_async(func = trytrytryshare, args = (args_l[i]))
    p.close()
    p.join()
    timecost = (dt.now()-st).total_seconds()
    print('%d threads finished in %f secs' %(thread,timecost))
    return timecost
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    res = DF(columns = ['thread','timecost'])
    n = 0
    for j in range(5):
        for i in range(1,8,3):
            timecost = trymultishare(thread = i,times = int(1e8)) 
            res.loc[n] = [i,timecost]
            n+=1
        timecost = trymultishare(thread = 70,times = int(1e8)) 
        res.loc[n] = [70,timecost]
        n+=1
    res_sum = res.groupby('thread').mean()
    res_sum['decay'] =  res_sum.loc[1,'timecost'] / res_sum['timecost']
```

on my own computer (8cores):
[image]

on my server (80 cores, im the only one using it)
[image]

i tried again, make one thread job longer.
[image]

the decay is really bad....

any idea how to "fix" this, or this is just what i can get when using multi-process?

thanks

Comment: Looks like you're getting confused over what threads and processes are. There's no multithreading going on here. There's also nothing in this code to show what you mean by "decay"

Comment: Your code is trying to use multiprocessing (wrongly). There is no multithreading. As you clearly haven't studied this subject very well I'm voting to close

Answer (score 1):

The way you're timing apply_async is flawed. You won't know when the subprocesses have completed unless you wait for their results.

It's a good idea to work out an optimum process pool size based on number of CPUs. The code that follows isn't necessarily the best for all cases but it's what I use.

You shouldn't set the pool size to the number of processes you intend to run. That's the whole point of using a pool.

So here's a simpler example of how you could test subprocess performance.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import perf_counter
from os import cpu_count

def process(n):
    r = 0
    for _ in range(n):
        r += 1
    return r

POOL = max(cpu_count()-2, 1)
N = 1_000_000

def main(procs):
    # no need for pool size to be bigger than the numer of processes to be run
    poolsize = min(POOL, procs)
    with Pool(poolsize) as pool:
        _start = perf_counter()
        for result in [pool.apply_async(process, (N,)) for _ in range(procs)]:
            result.wait() # wait for async processes to terminate
        _end = perf_counter()
    print(f'Duration for {procs} processes with pool size of {poolsize} = {_end-_start:.2f}s')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f'CPU count = {cpu_count()}')
    for procs in range(10, 101, 10):
        main(procs)
```

**Output:**

```
CPU count = 20
Duration for 10 processes with pool size of 10 = 0.12s
Duration for 20 processes with pool size of 18 = 0.19s
Duration for 30 processes with pool size of 18 = 0.18s
Duration for 40 processes with pool size of 18 = 0.28s
Duration for 50 processes with pool size of 18 = 0.30s
Duration for 60 processes with pool size of 18 = 0.39s
Duration for 70 processes with pool size of 18 = 0.42s
Duration for 80 processes with pool size of 18 = 0.45s
Duration for 90 processes with pool size of 18 = 0.54s
Duration for 100 processes with pool size of 18 = 0.59s
```

Comment: Hi Vlad, not sure what do u mean by "You shouldn't set the pool size to the number of processes you intend to run. That's the whole point of using a pool.",  if u mean im using more pool numbers than my CPU counts, then no im using 70 on a 80 core server.  and this is the output i get from running your code.

Comment: @rpking I'm running on a 10-core 3GHz Intel Xeon which os.cpu_count() interprets as 20 CPUs. Remember that there's really no point in creating a pool size greater than the number of available CPUs.

Comment: CPU count = 80, POOL size = 78
Duration for 10 processes = 0.13s
Duration for 20 processes = 0.14s
Duration for 30 processes = 0.14s
Duration for 40 processes = 0.17s
Duration for 50 processes = 0.20s
Duration for 60 processes = 0.21s
Duration for 70 processes = 0.23s
Duration for 80 processes = 0.25s
Duration for 90 processes = 0.30s
Duration for 100 processes = 0.32s

Comment: yea i know what u mean. but if my pool size is less than my CPU counts, then theoretically the duration of 1 process and 70 process should be very close -- they are running teh same job parallelly.  if one core cost 4 seconds, 70 core should cost maybe 6 seconds.  but it costing 15 seconds and that is my question.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're observing the cost of spawning new processes, since apply_async returns immediately. It's much cheaper to spawn one process in the case of thread==1 instead of spawning 70 processes (your last case with the worst decay).

The fact that the server with 80 cores performs better than you laptop with 8 cores could be due to the server containing better hardware in general (better heat removal, faster CPU, etc) or it might contain a different OS. Benchmarking across different machines is non-trivial.

Comment: hi the 80 cores server didnt perform better.. the efficiency of each core is only 27.8% when im using 70core ( sorry i named the column "decay" and i think that caused the confusion ).      also the cost to spawn process is negetable in this case ( i tried to spawn 70 threads and not calculating anything in each thread, all 70 threads cost abt 2seconds),  if one thread costs 4second, 70 threads cost 6 seconds, that might be the cost of spawn process, but the difference between 4 and 15seconds cant be explained by that.

Comment: Just to clear things up - were you spawning actual threads or processes?